# Laravel Trying to Get Property of Non-Object - Display Data from Different Table using API

Tags: laravel, api

I have two table:

1) ip status table
2) status table

In the database, status's id is the foreign key for ip status table. I want to display 'whitelist' instead of '2'

ip status table:

```
+==============+===============+============+
| ip_status_id |  ip_address   | status_id  |
+==============+===============+============+
|     1        |  192.108.1.1  |      2     |
+--------------+---------------+------------+
```

status table:

```
+============+================+
| status_id  |     status     |
+============+================+
|    1       |    Blacklist   |
+------------+----------------+
|    2       |    Whitelist   |
+------------+----------------+
```

and I call it through API with query like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT  * FROM tbl_ip_statuses left join 
    tbl_status on tbl_ip_statuses.status_id = tbl_status.status_id 
    WHERE tbl_ip_statuses.is_active = ? 
    AND tbl_ip_statuses.is_deleted = ? 
    group by tbl_ip_statuses.ip_status_id");

$stmt->bind_param("ii", $_GET["is_active"], $_GET["is_deleted"]);
```

And I do checking at controller, the data fetch exactly like I want

[image: checking result]

Here is my controller:

```
$listing = json_decode($ip_status);
//dd($listing);
return view('ip_status.listing')->with("ip_status", $listing);
```

Here is my view:

```
 @if($ip_status)
    @foreach($ip_status as $data)
        <td class="uk-width-1-2">{{ $data->s_ip }}</td>
        <td class="uk-width-1-2">{{ $data->s_status }}</td>
```

But then it show trying to get property `s_ip` of non object.

when I `print_r($listing)`

```
stdClass Object (
    [ip_statuses] => Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object (
            [ip_status_id] => 1
            [s_ip] => 192.108.1.1
            [status_id] => 2
            [is_active] => 1
            [ip_status_id_create] => 0
            [dt_create] => 2020-04-15 17:16:06
            [ip_status_id_edit] => 0 
            [dt_edit] => 
            [is_deleted] => 0 
            [ip_status_id_delete] => 0 
            [dt_delete] => 
            [s_status] => Whitelist 
            [status_id_create] => 0 
            [status_id_edit] => 0 
            [status_id_delete] => 0 
        )

        [1] => stdClass Object ( 
            [ip_status_id] => 2 
            [s_ip] => 1922.131.100.1 
            [status_id] => 1 
            [is_active] => 1 
            [ip_status_id_create] => 0 
            [dt_create] => 2020-04-15 17:15:29 
            [ip_status_id_edit] => 0 
            [dt_edit] => 
            [is_deleted] => 0 
            [ip_status_id_delete] => 0 
            [dt_delete] => 
            [s_status] => Blacklist 
            [status_id_create] => 0 
            [status_id_edit] => 0 
            [status_id_delete] => 0
        ) 

        [2] => stdClass Object ( 
            [ip_status_id] => 3
            [s_ip] => 1.1.1.1
            [status_id] => 2
            [is_active] => 1
            [ip_status_id_create] => 0
            [dt_create] => 2020-04-15 17:16:06 
            [ip_status_id_edit] => 0 
            [dt_edit] => 
            [is_deleted] => 0 
            [ip_status_id_delete] => 0 
            [dt_delete] => 
            [s_status] => Whitelist 
            [status_id_create] => 0
            [status_id_edit] => 0 
            [status_id_delete] => 0
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Could you please print out the value instead of dd. I.e print_r($listing);

Comment: @SachinKumar I edit it in question - the result of print_r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ip_statuses in an array as I see from dd result,
You can access s_ip an other elements like this $listing[‘s_ip’]

Update:

Your data is reaching blade as one ‘ip_statuses’ which have  array items inside, so you need to make a change in controller where you send data to view:

`return view(...)->with(‘ip_status’, $listing->ip_statuses);`

Comment: You means, put the code in the view files like that?

Comment: `@if($ip_status)
        @foreach($ip_status as $data)
<td class="uk-width-1-2" > {{$data['s_ip']}}}</td>` 

but it error undefined index s_ip

Comment: Yes exactly.. or $data.s_ip

Comment: Both did not work.
$data['s_ip'] - error undefined index,
$data.s_ip - Use of undefined constant

Comment: I edited my answer, and sorry for the short answers I am on my phone right now